# How does windows 8 manage stack of Pages in Frame?

Tags: .net, windows-8, windows-runtime

How does Windows 8 manage a stack of Pages in a Frame?

And how can I clear the whole stack programmatically, as in I need to 'pop' all pages in a stack and return to first page where I started from (let's say Login Page)?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the methods of [the Frame class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame)

In [this article](http://www.jayway.com/2012/05/25/clearing-the-windows-8-page-cache/) (a must read about navigation):

```
private void ResetPageCache()
{
    var cacheSize = ((Frame) Parent).CacheSize;
    ((Frame) Parent).CacheSize = 0;
    ((Frame) Parent).CacheSize = cacheSize;
}
```

Comment: i see...Still looking a for a better solution..!!

Comment: The article mentioned by Erno also talks about NavigationCacheMode (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.navigationcachemode.aspx) property of the Page class. With it - you can control how the pages are cached on a page by page basis.

Comment: @Erno I tried the code in that articles but i am left wondering with the same question again that "Why cant i clear my stack" because i can see the "Backstackdepth" property increasing continuously ..isnt caching a different phenomenon than the "Backstack" ??

Answer (score 3):

In the Common/LayoutAwarePage.cs there is the following GoHome() function (in addition to the GoBack() function used with the Click-event on the standard Back button):

```
    // Use the navigation frame to return to the topmost page
    if (this.Frame != null)
    {
        while (this.Frame.CanGoBack) this.Frame.GoBack();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing your own Frame class, something similar to this:

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/eshaham/archive/2012/04/30/fixing-frame-navigation-in-metro-style-apps.aspx

Then you could write a RemoveLastEntry method that basically does this:

```
void RemoveLastEntry()
{
    if (_navigationStack.Count > 0)
    {
        _navigationStack.Pop();
    }
}
```

and call this method a certain number of times.

Or you could call GoHome method which takes you back to the first screen (that would be clearing the whole stack except the first item).

I hope this'll take you in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

best solution would be

```
while (this.Frame.CanGoBack)
{
    this.Frame.GoBack();
}
```