# Force XAML page to reload

Tags: c#, windows, xaml

I'm trying to figure out how to force a page to completely initialise itself in C# and XAML programmatically (Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime).

(Note this isn't a question about data binding as not a few values need to be updated dynamically, the whole page needs to reinit itself).

The Page class is set up to cache itself as so -

```
this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
```

I have tried simple answers like setting

```
this = new Page();
```

Which doesn't work as current page is obviously read only.

Not entirely sure how to proceed as Page and Frame supply no obvious reload() method or equivalents.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works:

```
 Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
 if (rootFrame != null)
 {
     rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(Page));
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunatly this isn't working, probably due to the fact I have this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required; set in my Page class

Comment: You can try to temporarily clear the cache as in one of the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11326948/how-does-windows-8-manage-stack-of-pages-in-frame