# How to refresh a windows phone 8.1 page?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I want to refresh a Windows Phone 8.1 page and

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?" + DateTime.Now.Ticks, UriKind.Relative));
```

Does not work anymore because navigationservice is no longer supported in 8.1.
I don't want to navigate to the page, i want to refresh it with its values and ...

Comment: Have you considered using *INotifyPropertyChanged* interface, define suitable properties and when there is a need of an update, call *PropertyChanged*?

Comment: @Romasz Can you direct a little bit more? I am still inexperienced with a lot of stuff in c# and wp. I checked what you told me about but how should i implement them inside a button click?

Comment: First try to read some documentation: [about binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh758318.aspx) and [the mentioned interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695(v=vs.110).aspx). Once you get it, try to follow some tutorials regarding *INotifyPropertyChanged*, you will surely find a lot of them easily.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Phone 8.1, there is a Frame object associated to each Page. You should use the Frame object for Navigation.

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
```

Consider you haven't set the NavigationCacheMode to required. If yes, you may need to clear cache as explained here.

[How does windows 8 manage stack of Pages in Frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11326948/how-does-windows-8-manage-stack-of-pages-in-frame)